# What are recommended modules or processes which support rating based comments or reviews?

Tags: 7, comments, rating

I am new to Drupal and I am planning a directory site where users can review and rate the service of a shop or company.

I'm thinking of something like this (taken from yelp.com):

[image: Something like this]

Any recommended modules or processes which support such feature in Drupal 7, i.e. for rating based comments or reviews?

Comment: this site is not a place for requests like this - there are thousands of modules, you need to do some research and find ones that fit your specific need

Comment: I have searched but none of them are meeting the exact requirements.

Comment: you will almost never find a single module that does everything exactly how you want. You have to find individual modules that each do one part, and put them together to form what you want

Comment: That is what I want to know. Me & my team is new to Drupal. We have tried but did not work out.

Comment: see here. http://directory.repairmymobile.in/durga-communicatation-pachmin-vihar-new-delhi  We have got the comment section, but rating is not appearing along with it.

Comment: I assume by that last comment you have a rating module installed, so the question should be why that particular module is not showing, not a vague question on how to construct a general system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Rating

The [VotingAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) module (available for both D6 and D7) offers a framework to developers of Drupal modules about voting and/or rating. It uses a standardized API and schema for storing, retrieving, and tabulating votes for Drupal content.

VotingAPI offers these key features:

- Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete operations for voting data.
- Whenever a vote is casted, it calculates the results and caches them. These calculations can either be the default calculations (average, total, etc), or they can be implemented via custom tallying functions.
- Via its integration with the **Actions** module, it can trigger workflow steps whenever votes are casted and results are tallied, such as promoting a node to the front page, hiding a comment flagged as spam, or sending some eMail.
- It integrates with the **Views** module, which allows for slice and dice of the content of a site based on user consensus. And tt provides functions to format vote data to display them to users.

**Typical rating related modules with a stable release for D7**:

- [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) (D6 and D7).
- [Fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) (D6 and D7).
- [Voting API Bayesian](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi_bayesian) (D7).
- [Star Rating](https://www.drupal.org/project/starrating) (D7, no [VotingAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) dependency).
- [Raty](https://www.drupal.org/project/raty) (D7-beta2).

## Views / Rules / Flag / Message

Everything above relates to "Rating" (or voting). Some more modules that you may want to consider (= add to the mix of modules you might want to consider):

- The [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, which is typically combined with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module also to create all sorts of interesting site features. If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters. There is a similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-flag-with-nodeone) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.
- If you also add the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, you're already pretty close to a great mix of modules to create the site you're looking for. Maybe also review the [set of 30 video tutorials](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) about the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
- For more details about the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module, refer to some interesting [Use Cases](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180149) detailed within its [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145).